# Make a portable device based on Raspberry Pi

Tags: power-supply

I would like to use RP to create a portable Unix device, something like Nintendo DS. Has anybody have information about the monitor and the power I need to use to make RP as a portable device?

Comment: why on earth would you make a portable Pi? get an android phone, iphone, or maybe ipad or cheap chinese android pad, that already has all the bells and whistles -- touch screen, ARM processor, HDMI output, plenty of memory -- and start playing with it instead of pointlessly spending your time on this very time consuming endeavor.

Comment: @lenik I'm a software guy and want to learn about electronics, and to motivate myself I need to make it portable! Where is the fun on buying full packaged products?!

Comment: @lenik well the only limit is your imagination. Robotics comes straight to mind for portable pi projects or what if you wanted to make a solar powered rover for example or some kind of remote monitoring system?
I'm currently working on some wearable electronics which obviously will need to be portable.

Answer (score 4):

For monitor/screen information please read this : http://elinux.org/RPi_Screens 
You can find information which screen devices are supported. For example this guy uses 1.8" TFT LCD screen. 
http://www.whence.com/rpi/

For power supply i suggest USB portable batteries (power bank). I'm using Yoobao YB642 11300 mAh battery with my Rpi. http://www.yoobao.com/en/product.asp?b_id=143&a_id=295

Comment: How long can you run your Pi on the YooDao YB642?

Comment: @HeatfanJohn 11300mAh / 700mA = 16 hours approximately, or significantly less if you plug a lot of peripherals

Comment: I'm using Raspberry w/ BerryBoot (OS disk is USB stick), also there is a USB WIFI adapter plugged to connect network. So with that accessories it can run about 12-14 hours.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of the screen depending on your need you could have the pi connect to a phones local wifi hotspot and then shh into it with that phone (this works lovely on my iphone i am sure other platforms will have simialr apps)

+1 to using the usb portable batteries. you can get some pretty serious ones now that look similar to an external HDD in terms of size and weight that will power it for hours (probably outlast your phones battery life if that is the method of control you choose)

Answer (score 0):

Your goal is similar to a project of **[building laptop with RPi](http://blog.parts-people.com/2012/12/20/mobile-raspberry-pi-computer-build-your-own-portable-rpi-to-go/)** so you can learn from it.